# JFrame closes immediately when called in Ant InputHandler

Tags: ant, jframe

I've created a custom InputHandler for Ant in order to get some input using a GUI.  The issue is that the JFrame created immediately closes after the call to setVisible() instead of waiting for input.

Below is the simple code for the InputHandler and the frame it creates.

```
public class GUIInputHandler implements InputHandler
{
    public GUIInputHandler()
    {
        super();
    }

    public void handleInput(InputRequest input) throws BuildException
    {
        GUIFrame frame = new GUIFrame(input.getDefaultValue());

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now if I just create a main and create the frame and show it, everything is fine.  I could rig it to have some sort of loop with the frame triggering the exit condition but that is a hack.  Any ideas?